# AsyncTask in an android socket application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am making an android socket app to communicate with the server for creating accounts, and i noticed i have to do this in AsyncTask sub class, even when i seperate it to another class without UI,but i am terribly confused how can i use AsyncTask on this, is there any one expert here who can help me please?

this is the code:

```
public class AccountCreator extends Activity {

public AccountCreator(){
 super();
 }
// for I/O
ObjectInputStream sInput;       // to read from the socket
ObjectOutputStream sOutput;     // to write on the socket
 Socket socket;
public static String LOGTAG="Lifemate";
public String server = "localhost";  
public String username = "user"; 
public String password = "rezapassword" ;
public int port = 1400;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Log.i(LOGTAG,"oncreate called");
this.start();
}


AccountCreator(String server, int port, String username,String password) {
        this.server = "localhost";
        this.port = 1400;
        this.username = username;
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"first accountcreator called");
}

  public boolean start() {

      // try to connect to the server
//this method returns a value of true or false when called 

      try {
        socket = new Socket(server, port);
    }
        // if it failed not much I can so
    catch(Exception ec) {
//            display("Error connectiong to server:" + ec);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Error connectiong to server:" + ec);
        return false;
   }
    String msg = "Connection accepted " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + 
socket.getPort();
//        display(msg);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, msg);
    /* Creating both Data Stream */
    try
    {
        sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (IOException eIO) {
 //         display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + eIO);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + 
 eIO);
        return false;
    }

    // creates the Thread to listen from the server 

    // Send our username to the server this is the only message that we
    // will send as a String. All other messages will be ChatMessage objects
    try
    {
        sOutput.writeObject(username);
        sOutput.writeObject(password);

    }
    catch (IOException eIO) {
//          display("Exception doing login : " + eIO);
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Exception doing login : " + eIO);
        disconnect();
        return false;
    }
    // success we inform the caller that it worked
    return true;
}

 //            private void display(String msg) {
 //             TextView screenprint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.systemmessages);

 //             screenprint.setText(msg);


//    }

        private void disconnect() {
            Log.i(LOGTAG,"reached disconnect");
            try { 
                if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
            try {
                if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
            try{
                if(socket != null) socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
        }

  public void Begin() {             
      Log.i(LOGTAG,"it begun"); 
      int portNumber = 1400;
      String serverAddress = server;
      String userName = username;
      String newpassword = password;
 AccountCreator accountcreator = new AccountCreator(serverAddress, portNumber, 
 userName,password);

            if(!accountcreator.start())
            return;


  }
 }
```

i was trying to put whole code in Async, i dont know if was i right, do i need to do that also or just some parts of it?

Comment: I don't see an `AsyncTask` anywhere. Can you explain what part you are stuck on exactly? What is/isn't happening? It doesn't *have* to be in an `AsyncTask` but the socket work should be done in a background `Thread`

Comment: yes i tried several times to use Async on my code, but every time my codes were recieving terrible numbers of errors, when i run this app normal without Async, it returns ThreadException erorr.my main question is , cant i avoid using Async by a trick ? or extacly where in this code should i use it, because i srsly gave up on this method :/

Comment: First, you don't use regular constructors in an `Activity`...you use the `Activity` methods such as `onCreate()`. Second, as I said, the connection stuff needs to go inside of a background `Thread` which *can* be an `AsyncTask` and you do all of your connection work in `doInBackground()`. Currently, this question is way too broad. You need to show the current code you are using, meaning to put it in a separate `Thread` then explain *exactly* the problem you are having,

Comment: thanks mate for feedback, whole code is what im using, but this is a test code using static entries like username, not yet from input,but the whole code is needed for streaming, and by the way about Activity, should i change something you mean?

Comment: You definitely should change something...the things I told you. An `Activity` shouldn't have a normal constructor because you don't instantiate them like a normal Java class. Show how you are trying to use `AsyncTask` and what the problem is with it. If you aren't doing any UI stuff with the sockets then you can simply use another `Thread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, **`AsyncTask`** contains a few methods which may be helpful:

### `onPreExecute`:

- This method is the first block of code executed when calling `asyncTask.execute();` (runs on *mainUIThread*).

### `doInBackground`:

- Here you put all the code which may suspend you main UI (causes hang for your application) like internet requests, or any processing which may take a lot of memory and processing. (runs on *background* thread), contains one parameter taken from the `asyncTask.execute(ParameterType parameter);`

### `onPostExecute`

- Runs after `doInBackground()`. Its parameter is the return value of the `doInBackground` function, and mainly you put the changes in UI need to be done after the connection is finished (runs on *mainUIThread*)

Comment: This is a good quick overview of `AsyncTask` but I don't see where it pertains to the OP's current problem.

Comment: @codeMagic I am just giving him the way to sort his code between the functions of `Asynctask` if this is the problem for him

Comment: yes i fixed the start() method into the AsyncTask and it looks good now , tnx alot dude for your effort,and i think i got what you meant about Activity, the whole process must not be done in 1 class you mean i shall call the methods of this class from another right?

Comment: Best practice yes you should separate your `Activity` and `AsyncTask` and you should better make a new class for requesting the URL connection and parsing the response.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare another class within the class you have already created.

```
class SomeName extends Async<Void, String, Void>{ 

    protected void OnPreExecute(){
        // starts the task runs on main UI thread
        // Can be used to start a progress dialog to show the user progress
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        // does what you want it to do in the background
        // Connected to the server to check a log-in
        return result;
    }

    protected void OnPostExecute(Void result){
        // finishes the task and can provide information back on the main UI thread
        // this would be were you would dismiss the progress dialog
    }
}
```